# AngularJS and text-angular: Change CSS style for input placeholder

Tags: html, css, angularjs, input, placeholder

On wiki page of text-angular github project, it says:

https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Styling-the-Editor

I tried with this code:

```
 <div text-angular="text-angular" ta-toolbar="[]" ng-model="message"
         placeholder="<div class='placeholder'>Write Coment...</div>"></div>
```

But the screen will show as:
[placeholder show as raw html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0QXq.png)

I tried the following after taking a look at this website: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

```
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: red; }
```

It still didn't work. How can I give custom styles to my input placeholder?

Comment: I don't think you can have a `placeholder` inside a `div`...

Comment: define a placeholder with input

Comment: It also depends on your browser. See my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way myself.. To let the Answer part standing out to other similar questions, I choose to post answer here instead of editing original question.

Use .placeholder-text class. It's not a customized class but it's the temporary class used by text-angular when it is displaying placeholder.

```
.ta-bind {
 &.placeholder-text {
    color: red;
 }
 &:not(.placeholder-text) {
    color: black;
 }
}
```

( Example is in scss, remember to covert if you are using css)

Answer (score 4):

`placeholders` should be used with input elements and not on divs. You'd probably have to change your div tags to `inputs`.

You had the right idea about styling a placeholder, but you may need to adjust the vendor prefixes depending on your browser

**Chrome, Safari, Opera, Edge)**: ::-webkit-input-placeholder

**Firefox 4 through 18**: :-moz-placeholder (Only one colon)

**Firefox 19+**: ::-moz-placeholder (two colons)

**IE 10 and IE 11** :-ms-input-placeholder

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera and Edge */
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: red; }
/* Firefox 4 through 18 */
:-moz-input-placeholder { color: red; }
/* Firefox 19+ */
::-moz-input-placeholder { color: red; }
/* IE10 and IE11 */
:-ms-input-placeholder { color: red; }
```

```html
<input placeholder="Content here" />
```

Another thing you could try is to attach a `contenteditable` property to your div which will make it behave kind of like an input element. You can then set a data property to simulate the behavior of a placeholder.

Use the `before` pseudo selector which will target the div only when it's empty and not focused on.

```css
[contenteditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
  content:attr(data-text);
  color: red;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" data-text="Enter text here"></div>
```

Comment: This woks fine for other html input control. But I actually was asking about the particular case of text-angular. Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work for this control..